# Is it possible to make a Composable appear with animation when the activity is started?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation

I want to make some parts of my UI appear with an animation **when the activity is started**. For example, if my activity's `onCreate` looks like:

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        AppTheme{
            // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
            ) {
                Text(text = "Message")
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I make the Text appear with a fade in animation? Most Jetpack Compose animations require a state that can be changed by performing some activity (e.g. tapping a button).

I tried using `AnimatedVisibility` with the argument set to `true`, but this didn't give an animation and was as if there was no `AnimatedVisibility`.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7yY2OocGiQU

Comment: @CodePoet this describes how to add an appearance animation for components that can be enabled with an action (i.e. pressing a button enables some TextField), whereas I want the animation to appear when the activity is started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this code block:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        /*MainView()*/
        setContent {
            var visible by remember {
                mutableStateOf(false)
            }
            LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit, block = {
                delay(600L)
                visible = true
            })
            AnimatedVisibility(
                visible = visible, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                enter = fadeIn(initialAlpha = 0.0f) + slideInVertically(
                    tween(
                        durationMillis = 600,
                        delayMillis = 600,
                        easing = FastOutSlowInEasing
                    ),
                    initialOffsetY = { it * 6 }
                )

            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Message",
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    fontSize = 20.sp
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: The AnimatedVisibility works reacting to a simple boolean value. So its always better to provide boolean value which is state knowing varible in AnimatedVisibility's visible argument.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. It is helpful, and yes it works. BUT: To me it is too complicated to have to do such a natural thing with so much code. Plus the delay there, isn't it crazy? How did you come to those 600? Is it enough on slow devices?

Comment: The delay is just for reference purpose - you can keep any variable over there instead of `visible` whose value can change and trigger state update!

Answer (score 0):

This is just an extension of the solution provided by Megh above, all credit goes to Megh...

As I am doing this repeatedly, I wrapped it to make it reusable.

```
@Composable
internal fun InitialFadeIn(durationMs: Int = 1000, content: @Composable() AnimatedVisibilityScope.() -> Unit) {
    var visibility by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit, block = { visibility = true })
    AnimatedVisibility(visible = visibility, enter = fadeIn(tween(durationMs)), content = content)
}
```

**Note:**

- I removed the delay at all, as I do not want any extra delays
- I tested it, and it seems to be working on multiple different devices, so hopefully, it is OK